# Amazon S3 - Upfront File Organization Architectural Decisions

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm currently building a web application for a publishing platform, and I am using S3 for content storage. S3 is super simple to use, but I'd like to try to make the best possible file organization up-front.

Here is an idea of the shape of my data:

### Publications

- Publications have descriptions (text)
- Introduction (text + images)
- Discussion (text + images)
- have many experiments

### Experiments

- Experiments have descriptions (text)
- Results (text + images)
- Methods (text + images)
- Discussion (text + images)

### Organizational Models

**Model #1: Flat Buckets**

This model seems pretty obviously bad, but I'm including for completeness.

*Publication Images Bucket:*

```
publication_images/[publication-id]-[name].png
```

*Publication Text Bucket:*

```
publication_text/[publication-id]-[name].txt
```

*Experiment buckets same as above*

**Model #2: Publication/Experiment Objects**

*Publications Bucket:*

```
[publication-id]/text/[name].txt

[publication-id]/images/[name].png
```

*Experiments bucket is analogous*

**Model #3: Experiments Within Publications**

*Publications Bucket:*

```
[publication-id]/text/[name].txt
[publication-id]/images/[name].png
[publication-id]/experiments/[experiment_id]/images/[name].png
[publication-id]/experiments/[experiment_id]/text/[name].txt
```

**Model #4/5: Publications/Experiments Get Their Own Buckets**

This is essentially the same as #2 and #3 above, except that instead of each publication or experiment being an object in a publications or experiments bucket, it would get it's own bucket. This doesn't really seem to be the way things are done, but I am a beginner with S3 so I could be wrong.

There are definitely other ways to organize this, but these are the main ones I've come up with. I'm leaning toward Model #2 or #3, depending on if I want to fetch all of my experiment content with the publication or not. That being said, do any of these models look obviously superior or inferior to anyone with more experience? Are there trade-offs I should be aware of and consider now when planning for the future? Are there other models that would be better for performance and/or clarity that I've overlooked?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't particularly matter - S3 doesn't have folders, they're just illusory constructs. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html "Amazon S3 has a flat structure with no hierarchy like you would see in a typical file system. However, for the sake of organizational simplicity, the Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept as a means of grouping objects. Amazon S3 does this by using key name prefixes for objects."

Comment: Do note, though, the performance recommendations at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html, particularly "Add a Hex Hash Prefix to Key Name". Not important if you sit CloudFront in front of S3, though.